# `conda activate` not working in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, anaconda

I am running Windows PowerShell inside or outside VS Code in Windows 10, and I am not able to activate or change the virtual environment. I have the full Anaconda installed on my system (this should probably pop up for Miniconda too).

I have already tried the following solutions following other answers here or solutions on the web:

1. Ensured `PATH` environment variable points to `<anaconda_dir>/Scripts`
2. Ran `conda init` prior to and after running `conda activate <env_name>`
3. Tried solutions provided on https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9392

Comment: "I am not able to activate or change the virtual environment." - Why. What happens.

Comment: I can't remember now, but I think it was some bug that got solved then. Thanks!